# How to get UIView to layout properly before making it into an image

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout

I am using this code to render a UIView into an image

```
-(UIImage *)getImageForView:(UIView *)aView {     
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(aView.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
[aView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return viewImage;
}
```

The issue that I am having is that the view is not set out properly using autolayout. What should I do.

I currently create a UIView "viewA" with a frame which is the correct size for my view and then create my complicated intended view "ViewB" (which has auto layout on) and then add viewB as a subview to "viewA"  then i give viewA to my above method.

First I thought viewA would not have to be added to some superview but it does not layout properly, should I be adding viewA with an alpha of 0 to a superview, then I assume maybe an "layoutIfNeeded" could be used but on which view should I do this?

**Edit: Here is the code that creates the UIView**

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 439)];

//This is the UIView that contains a lot of views
MyView *myView = [[MyView alloc] init];

myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

[view addSubview:myView];

[view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                      constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[myView(439)]"
                      options:0
                      metrics:nil
                      views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(myView)]];

[view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                      constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[myView(320)]"
                      options:0
                      metrics:nil
                      views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(myView)]];
```

**What Worked for me in the end**

```
[myView layoutIfNeeded];
[view layoutIfNeeded];
```

In other words calling it on both views.

Comment: show the code for the view creation and adding the subview. are you setting the frames?

Comment: Done. Looking forward to your thoughts.

Comment: Try: MyView *myView = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame: view.bounds];

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Send your view a `layoutIfNeeded` message before rendering it in your image context.

Comment: I was going to answer this myself but you are pretty much right.  It seems I need to call this on both views.  First on myView then on the other view.  It then lays out properly.